# How do I resize and pad an image to a given size using imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, image-editing

Say I have a directory of images which is variously `3024×4032` and `4032×3024` pixels, and I want them all resized to `1920×1080`.

I want that exact output size, but I don't want the images distorted to fit the size, so I want the edges padded with black as needed to preserve the aspect ratio of the original images. What is the ImageMagick command line to pad the images as needed?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For each image this command will produce a `1920x1080` version of the image, centered, with the edges padded in black where needed:

```
convert [input file] -resize 1920x1080 -background black -gravity center -extent 1920x1080 [output file]
```

Source: [ImageMagick documentation for the `-extent` flag](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#extent).

Comment: Would you accept you own answer, to be easily found.

Comment: I think as of some version -extend is no longer a valid option.

Comment: @Andy It is -extent.

Comment: Note that the order is important: `-gravity center -extent …` is not the same as `-extent … -gravity center`.